# Precision loss in JSON to ION conversion for numeric values containing exponents

Tags: java, json, amazon-ion

As per [ION Cookbook](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/cookbook.html#migrating-json-data-to-ion), these are rules for converting numeric values in JSON to ION:

```
1. Numeric values without a decimal point are interpreted as Ion integers
2. Numeric values with a decimal point but without an exponent are interpreted as Ion decimals
3. Numeric values with exponents are interpreted as Ion floats
```

Why numeric values with exponents are converted to float? Is there some specification that is being followed?

I am converting JSON record containing exponent to ION record. How can I preserve the precision in this case? I am using [Ion Java](https://github.com/amzn/ion-java) library.

```java
String payload = "{\"abc\":\"aa\",\"xyz\":1232323232320003434234222222222223333333333333333311111112321234e-49}";
final IonValue value = ION.singleValue(payload);
System.out.println(value); // {abc:"aa",xyz:1.2323232323200034E14}
```